# Counting repeated elements in a singly linked list using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, singly-linked-list

I have two functions, one being a helper function that makes recursion count the number of repeated items.

For the singly linked list with {97,92,97,80,97} the result should be 3 (as 97 is repeated 3 times), however it returns one. Why is it so?

```cpp
template <typename Data_t>
Data_t SLinkedList<Data_t>::Freq() {
    
    Node* ptr = _head;
    Data_t element;
    ptr->_data = element;
    return FreqHelper(element);
    
}
template <typename Data_t>
Data_t SLinkedList<Data_t>::FreqHelper(Data_t element) {
    
    unsigned int count = 0;
    if(empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(_head->_data == element) {
        _head = _head->_next;
        FreqHelper(_head->_next->_data);
        count++;
        
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why does your `Freq` function overwrite the `data` of the head node?

Comment: Also you generally want to use the computed value of a recursive function, which your `FreqHelper` does not do (it ignores the result of the call completely)

Comment: Try replacing `FreqHelper(_head->_next->_data); count++;` with `count += FreqHelper(_head->_next->_data);`

Answer (score 0):

To use recursion either your recursive function returns a number or it doesn't in which case you can keep a global variable count. You are mixing both approaches. Also you need a base case where you stop your recursion.

Either

```
template <typename Data_t>
Data_t SLinkedList<Data_t>::FreqHelper(Data_t element,Node *t) {

     if(t==nullptr)return 0;

     int count=t->_data==element?1:0;
    
     return count+FreqHelper(element,t->next);
 }
```

Or

```
template <typename Data_t>
    void SLinkedList<Data_t>::FreqHelper(Data_t element,Node *t) {
    
         if(t==nullptr)return;
         if(t->_data==element)++count; //count is assumed a global variable
         FreqHelper(element,t->_next);
     }
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using global variables, those are a really bad idea. If anything the alternative to returning a value would be to have an "out parameter" (a reference parameter that the function modifies)

Comment: what does element=?1:0 mean?

Comment: I agree with you. I wasn’t recommending I just tried to keep the code as close as possible to his initial version

Comment: @sadboy99 it is like if else statement. Count is assigned 1 if t->_data==element and 0 otherwise